# Returning error messages from a model subcomponent in MVP

Tags: c#, model, error-handling, mvp

I am confused as to how one is supposed to send messages to the user (like in a MessageBox) from a sub-component.  Say I have code like this:

```
class Model
{
    public void somethingToDo()
    {
        SomethingElse aSubComponent = new SomethingElse();

        aSubComponent.doSomethingThatCanError();
    }
}

class SomethingElse
{
    public void doSomethingThatCanError()
    {
        if(/* Everything is fine */ )
        {
            DoWhatWeAreSupposedToDo();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowAnErrorMessageBoxSomehow();
        }
    }
}
```

If the error was just in the model, one way I solved this was to raise a message that the Presenter listens for, and then from there run something on the view to show the message box.  When code that can error is in another class, I can think of several ways (like forwarding the event from that sub-component), but that seems messy.

I could also use Exceptions, but would that really be the right way to go on this?

What is the appropriate way to show a message to the user on the view, from a sub-component of a model in MVP?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a ModelState.AddModelError() and reference this in the view. 
The other choice you have is to throw an exception, or create custom exceptions and then reference them as necessary. eg.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(aExample) {

 ModelState.AddModelError("Example", "Example is required");

  }
```

Comment: You can then output this to a view as you'd like*